# Future perfect or simple in this context

Tags: grammar, translation, future, perfect-aspect

In a movie I saw, a young boy told to an old man that he would be gone for a long time when something happens. I'm trying to figure out what the boy actually said and what tense should have been used (heard dubbed version).

Could it be:

> You will have been gone for a long time by then.
>    You will be gone for a long time by then.
>   You will not have been here for a long time by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three samples, the first (with its [future perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect) form) is more natural than the others.  Absent special context, neither the second nor the third is a likely or plausible utterance by a native speaker, the third being least likely because of its stilted and negative form.

I think the following form is more likely to be heard (but no definitive answer to your question can be given unless you identify the movie, the characters, and the scene, so that someone can look up what actually was said):

> You'll be long gone by then.

Comment: Thanks. The context does not matter much - a young boy is talking to an old man (like 90) about something that is going to happen in like 50 years..he means that like "you will not live that long". I do not need to know exactly what they said int he movie but what would you said as native speakers ;)

Comment: @user970696, the expression "long gone" is often used; see edit.